# Telerik KendoUI Mvc SSRS Slow

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, telerik-mvc

So I recently installed Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC and it seems to have totally bodged my SSDT/SSRS projects in visual studio. The projects work but can take upwards of 20-30 seconds to save making them basically unusable.

Originally we thought this issue may have been have been something to do with ReSharper however having contacted their support and done some captures they said that it looked like Telerik was the culprit.

[Extract from the capture trace here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSEDn.png)

Having uninstalled Telerik completely low and behold my save speeds go back to normal (less than a second).

Now full disclaimer - we are not using the most up to date version of Telerik (it's a slightly older version 2018.2.620) as this is the version we are licensed for which I would like to think wouldn't make a difference but putting it here just in case!

Has anyone else experienced this issue with SSRS projects? It's strange as, as far as I can tell, there is nothing in the project that should be referencing any MVC/Telerik code.

We have tried this on multiple machines and all seem to suffering the same problem although looking at Google I can't find anyone else reporting the same issue... Annoyingly I can't post of the telerik forums directly as they only let you do that if you have an active account...

If anyone can assist I would really appreciate it!